# In which log should I check for udev errors?

Tags: linux, debian, logs, udev

I've written a `udev` rule which is run each time my device is mounted/dismounted.

However, in which Linux (Debian) error log should I check when debugging such rules?

Answer (score 30):

You can change logging priority to "info" level or even "debug" by:

```
udevadm control --log-priority=info
```

Then you should see all logs in your system log. If you don't, then `rsyslogd` may not be configured to read kernel logs and you may still view the kernel logs using `dmesg`.

When you are done, bring it to default "err". See in `/etc/udev/udev.conf` what is your default logging level.

Comment: I am confused why there are two points of configuration for logging priority. Care to explain how `udevadm control --log-priority=info` is different from setting `udev_log="err"` in `/etc/udev/udev.conf`? Thanks

Comment: The `udevadm`method is to change the logging priority of the _running_ `udevd`; `udev.conf` is for permanently changing it.

Comment: Log priority `info` was not sufficient for me to see logs in `journalctl`; I needed to bump it to `debug`.

Answer (score 14):

`unbuffer udevadm monitor --environment`
The use of `unbuffer` is optional, but when piping output to `grep` saves you a headache. By default output is buffered in 4k blocks, nothing will be printed until that buffer is full.

You didn't forget to reload the rules?
`sudo udevadm control --reload`

Comment: Should be noted that `unbuffer` is not installed by default on Debian.

Comment: That's correct, it is in the expect-dev package. It can be installed by `sudo apt-get install expect-dev` un Debian/Ubuntu.