# How to rsync files when a USB stick is mounted

Tags: scripting, rsync, udev, usb-drive

Tried a little project to aid in transferring control files from my home computer to my work shop computer. The outcome confuses me. What am I doing wrong?

The home computer is running Fusion 360 under Windows.
The shop computer runs Debian Wheezy with rtai for LinuxCNC. It has no network connection.

Fusion 360 generates numerical control files onto a USB stick, I bring the stick to the shop for processing.
I would like when I plug the stick into the shop computer that all NC files get synced to the LinuxCNC  working folder.

I have made this udev rule
/etc/udev/rules.d/80-LARS.rules

```
ACTION=="add",SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="0951",ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Kingston",RUN+="/home/la/synch.sh"
```

synch.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
logger startsync
sudo rsync -a /media/LARS_GREJOR/NGC/* /home/la/linuxcnc/nc_files/
touch /home/la/now.done
logger donesync
```

I put a mark in syslog and then unplug and replug the USB stick.
Why so many syslog entries from my script?
And no files are copied. If I run synch.sh manually, the files get copied.

I have NOPASSWD:ALL set for group sudo. Tried rsync with and without sudo.

```
la@debianRT:~/linuxcnc/nc_files$logger  mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
la@debianRT:~/linuxcnc/nc_files$sudo tail -50 /var/log/syslog
Mar 20 21:46:14 debianRT kernel: [ 2646.615824] FAT-fs (sdb1): utf8 is not a recommended IO charset for FAT filesystems, filesystem will be case sensitive!
Mar 20 21:47:51 debianRT la: mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
Mar 20 21:48:07 debianRT kernel: [ 2759.410620] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 4
Mar 20 21:48:27 debianRT kernel: [ 2780.064015] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
Mar 20 21:48:27 debianRT kernel: [ 2780.198530] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1603
Mar 20 21:48:27 debianRT kernel: [ 2780.198534] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar 20 21:48:27 debianRT kernel: [ 2780.198537] usb 1-5: Product: DataTraveler 2.0
Mar 20 21:48:27 debianRT kernel: [ 2780.198539] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Kingston
Mar 20 21:48:27 debianRT kernel: [ 2780.198541] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 20070620000000005918801B
Mar 20 21:48:27 debianRT kernel: [ 2780.199267] scsi6 : usb-storage 1-5:1.0
Mar 20 21:48:27 debianRT mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5"
Mar 20 21:48:27 debianRT mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Mar 20 21:48:27 debianRT logger: startsync
Mar 20 21:48:27 debianRT logger: donesync
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT logger: startsync
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT logger: donesync
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT logger: startsync
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT logger: donesync
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT logger: startsync
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT logger: donesync
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT logger: startsync
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT kernel: [ 2781.196803] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT kernel: [ 2781.197395] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT kernel: [ 2781.200667] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 7888896 512-byte logical blocks: (4.03 GB/3.76 GiB)
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT kernel: [ 2781.201159] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT kernel: [ 2781.201163] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT kernel: [ 2781.201660] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT kernel: [ 2781.201664] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT kernel: [ 2781.204289] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT kernel: [ 2781.204294] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT kernel: [ 2781.322475]  sdb: sdb1
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT kernel: [ 2781.324537] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT kernel: [ 2781.324541] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT kernel: [ 2781.324544] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT logger: donesync
Mar 20 21:48:28 debianRT logger: startsync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT logger: donesync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT logger: startsync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT logger: startsync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT logger: startsync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT logger: startsync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT logger: donesync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT logger: donesync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT logger: donesync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT logger: donesync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT logger: startsync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT logger: donesync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT logger: startsync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT logger: donesync
Mar 20 21:48:29 debianRT kernel: [ 2782.085316] FAT-fs (sdb1): utf8 is not a recommended IO charset for FAT filesystems, filesystem will be case sensitive!
la@debianRT:~/linuxcnc/nc_files$
```

Comment: What actually happens when `sudo` runs in your script? If it doesn't have special permissions, it will fail asking for a password. (You can test the return code after it runs.) You thought of this and modified the group sudo in `/etc/sudoers`. So, *if* your user is a member of that group, the command will work when you run it manually. But, what user is active when udev runs the script and is that user a member of the sudo group?

Comment: It does run, but why does it run so many times?

Comment: Rsync returns with error code 23 when run after a 10 sec delay after udev invocation.

Comment: 23 is partial transfer due to error. To see what it's doing you should add  the `i` and `v` flags to show you each step it's taking and `--log-file=path_to_log_file` so it saves it for review. When they get questions like this on the rsync list, that's often the first thing they suggest. If you can see precisely what's failing, there's a much better chance of solving it.

Comment: I don't know much about udev, but maybe looking at its log set for more information may give you a clue as to why it appears to be running your script multiple times. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36251/in-which-log-should-i-check-for-udev-errors#36255 .

Comment: I was staring at that log. At one point, it looks like udev started your script and then the system recognized the drive and connected it - while your script was running. That can't be good. It almost looks like the system is retrying to connect to it and triggering udev multiple times. But that's just a guess. Have you tried another flash drive or tested that one https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck.vfat ? It also complaints about UTF-8 file names. I don't know if that's an issue or not. *fat systems don't even really support lower case names, let alone multibyte characters.

Comment: I missed the part about you physically replugging the device after placing the mark. What mark? The logger command in the script runs after the device is plugged in. rsync starts immediately after that. Also, I believe udev triggers things when they are unplugged as well as when they are plugged in. Could that explain some of the apparent extra invocations?

Comment: The mark is a string of mmmmmmmmmmmm that I injected into syslog. Then I unplugged the USB stick and after 5 seconds plugged it into another USB port. Several issues here, the most puzzling is the many invocations of my script.